# Why are my off-camera flashes not firing with my triggers?

Tags: troubleshooting, off-camera-flash, studio-lighting

I have a Canon 7D, Viscio Softboxes, Phottix trigger/receivers, and two external flashes: Nissin and Sony. My camera and softboxes work fine with Phottix trigger and receivers. The issue is that neither flash will work. The Nissin works fine with the Canon internal flash but not the Phottix transmitter. Is there any way to get either flash to trigger? (I want to use one for fill.)

Both flashes are set to channel 1 so I assume the frequency is different. I probably should have purchased the Viscio trigger but I might have the same issue...ugh.

Comment: When you say "Both flashes are set to channel 1" do you mean the triggers attached to then are on channel 1? or that you're setting the wireless channels of the flash? Can you clarify the flash models you're using? Also, which Phottix triggers are you using? Ares? Strato? Odin? And if Strato or Odin, are they for Canon or Sony? Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: Not enough information. Post the EXACT models of triggers and flashes, plus the flash and camera settings.

Answer (score 1):

If the Nissin works fine with the Canon's built in flash that means it is set to "optical slave" mode and is ignoring any signals from the hotshoe connected to the Phottix *radio* trigger. You need to set it just as if it were mounted on the camera's hot shoe, because the radio trigger is sending it the same signals that it would receive if it were mounted on the camera's hot shoe.

Some cameras and their flashes have an entirely different pin arrangement on the hot shoe connector from other systems. Most systems have a common position of the main pin that tells the flash to "fire" when using manual mode. But some Sony cameras and their flashes have an entirely different pin arrangement that makes setting the power manually on the flash and telling it when to "fire" with a generic manual trigger impossible. You need to confirm that the connections on the Sony flash have a central "fire" pin rather than the staggered four pin arrangement on their [iISO/Auto Lock Accessory Shoe](https://www.mhohner.de/sony-minolta/flashcomp_techref.php).

Comment: I confirmed the Sony flash does not have a central main pin but a staggered 2 and 2 arrangement. I guess I will have to use the Canon on camera flash to pre-trigger the Nissin off camera flash and the softboxes to trigger off the flash. But, today I took some pictures of my son and lowered the power (50% of front main)  the side (45 degrees) softbox and no shadow. So fill is not really required, correct? Any comments on softbox power and angles would also be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You're making it very difficult to help you by not fully explaining your setup. What do you mean when you say, "...trigger the softboxes?" Softboxes are modifiers, not lights. What type of lights are placed inside the softboxes? Front main means nothing if you don't tell us which light you are using for that position. Is that a light inside one of the softboxes or something else? Without knowing the guide number of each light, what modifier is being used with it, and how far it is placed from the subject it is impossible for us to visualize your setup.